# json php mysql получить значения

Tags: php, mysql, json

как получить два значения vipb и vipe из массива

```
{"vipb":"2018-03-29 01:30:00","vipe":"2018-03-30 01:30:00","sdaysb":"2018-03-29 01:30:00","sdayse":"2018-05-05 01:30:00","tdaysb":"2018-03-29 01:30:00","tdayse":"2018-04-29 01:30:00","ob":"0"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$decoded = json_decode($your_str);
// $decoded->vipb;
// $decoded->vipe;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще то это не массив, а объект.

Для `mysql` (есть в тегах вопроса)

```
select field->>"$.vipb", field->>"$.vipe"
from your_table
```